# retreiving qr code from database ionic/cordova

Tags: php, cordova, ionic-framework

So in my the ionic app, what i'm trying to do is,
scan a qr code ,search for it in my database ,
and echo a message saying it exists or it doesn't,
the qr code goes into the nglf variable like this,

```
   <ion-button (click)="scan()">bnnn</ion-button>

       <div nglf ="scannedData.text">

       <label>Your barcode </label>
```

how can i do that using php backend